# Define new variable according to the range of the values of another variable

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, range

This is a python function, which set the value for variable `cor` depending on the value of another variable (`num_heavy_atoms`): if `num_heavy_atoms` is in range `[1:10]`, `cor=1.0`, if `num_heavy_atoms` is in range `[11:20]`, `cor=2.0`, etc.

```
def determine_cor(num_heavy_atoms):
    if num_heavy_atoms >= 1 and num_heavy_atoms <= 10:
        cor = 1.0
    elif num_heavy_atoms >= 11 and num_heavy_atoms <= 20:
        cor = 2.0
    elif num_heavy_atoms >= 21 and num_heavy_atoms <= 30:
        cor = 3.0
    elif num_heavy_atoms >= 31 and num_heavy_atoms <= 40:
        cor = 4.0
    elif num_heavy_atoms >= 41 and num_heavy_atoms <= 50:
        cor = 5.0
    elif num_heavy_atoms > 50:
        cor = 6.0
    return cor
```

Is it possible to rewrite this function in more compact way to avoid all of those `elif`, and  define at the beginning all of the possible range for the variable (`num_heavy_atoms`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and compute the key from `num_heavy_atoms`:

```py
cor_values = {i: i+1 for i in range(5)}
cor = cor_values.get((num_heavy_atoms-1) // 10, 6)
```

This assumes `num_heavy_atoms >= 1` which seems reasonable for your application.

Alternatively you can compute `cor` directly from `num_heavy_atoms` in the following way:

```py
cor = (num_heavy_atoms-1) // 10 + 1
cor = min(cor, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function.

```
def determine_cor(num_heavy_atoms):
    heavy_atoms = [10,20,30,40,50]
    for i , val in enumerate(heavy_atoms, start=1):
        if num_heavy_atoms <= val :
            return i    
    return 6
```